# Automated Email Triggers(**NOT** Exact Targets Triggers, my own internal triggers)

Tags: api, webservices, marketing-cloud

This is where I am right now. Basically, I have a Trigger internal to our company, when this trigger is invoked, it looks for customers who meet a particular requirement such as being older then 42;

The goal was to make use of our existing license with Exact Target, and E-Mail these matched customers when a Trigger locates them.. Each Trigger can have its own unique FromName/FromEmailAddress; Each Trigger may also have it's own unique Subject.

A **LIST** changes each day, while the Subscriber List provided by Exact Target expects fairly static data.. I can CREATE a **LIST** and associate it with the Matched customers each day by appending them to that STATIC list. **THE PROBLEM** is that when I choose to now Send an Email to only the NEWLY added Subscribers, it becomes difficult, I can add a **FILTER** and send ONLY to those who are new such as an subscriber attribute/column "EmailToday" being set to "1"; However, this means that after sending each list, I must go back and update the subscriber list to change that column to "1"; **THE SUB-PROBLEMS** a) This column changes before the Email Send Definition actually processes the filter and SEND the e-mail(in my tests, this is certainly not immediate); and b) I now have to maintain a potentially large LIST and Update it periodically to set old customers to "1" and new customers to "0" if they're already in the LIST; These are the problems I am having currently. Can someone PLEASE shed some light on an appropriate approach.

**OPTIONS I'VE CONSIDERED**; Create a single list of all customers, update this list each day. Create **EXACT TARGET TRIGGERS** which reflect/mirror the ones I've created internally; Then I can allow ET to take care of this as intended.. However the **PROBLEMS** here is that now it becomes more difficult to maintain an established link between ET triggers and specific details such as SenderProfile, and Email Subject/Template changing between **MY SYSTEMS INTERNAL TRIGGERS**;

Looking forward to a response.

**NOTE** It boils down to me just wanting to do ONE time e-mail bursts, with the ability of keeping track of Unsubscribes; Which requires a Single List which is never deleted.. which makes this difficult, I also need to perform Tracking, and so I am concerned I cannot delete the Send Definition either;

If it was possible to create a list, always update this list with new emails, just to maintain un-subscribes, be able to DELETE SendDefinition without loosing Tracking of it, and specify specifically which emails out of the List are going to be e-mailed through this SendDefinition, then things would be golden.

Comment: Hi Kyle.  Welcome to the Salesforce Stack Exchange.  I added the [tag:exacttarget] tag to your question, so that those that follow that tag will be more likely to be aware of your question.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the Send Definition portion - what is the reasoning behind tracking the specific send definition?

Comment: Tracking is based on Job ID which is where Send Definition(Perform) comes in via the Web Service.. I am returned the "TaskID";

Comment: JobID's get assigned to emails that have been sent - the send definition simply connects all the pieces of a send for simplicity. You can execute a send definition, as opposed to performing a send, with the email, list, sender profile, etc in the code.  Send definition is more for setting up an automation. Which object is giving you TaskID? I'm not finding that in the [WSDL] (https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl)

Comment: Sorry just re-reading your edits, which seems to change the question a bit. Your question is really broad, and I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what your use case is here.  It might be good for you and I to catch up next week and discuss your use case in detail, so I can help you get to something you can use.

Comment: I narrowed it down in the **NOTE** section.

`PerformResult[] pResults = api.Perform(new PerformOptions(), "start", new InteractionBaseObject[] { sEmailSendDefinition }, out cStatus, out cStatusMessage, out cRequestID);
            var taskID = pResults[0].Task.ID;
            Console.WriteLine("Tracking ID: {0}", taskID);`

I'd like to discuss over e-mail skype if possible; my email is kgibbar@forcemktg.com

Comment: Phone is also an option; office number is 678-208-0667 ext 1195 (Kyle Gibbar)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12293/discussion-between-kyle-gibbar-and-kelly-j-andrews)

Comment: Still ready for a phone call if you're available Kelly.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely what you are looking to do here, is to associate these sends with a campaign.

[Here is a link to campaign info](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/campaigns/)

Since our tracking is per email send, and not by send definition, associating your individual sends to a campaign will help you get a better understanding of how the collective group of sends perform.

Hope this helps!